# two inputs within subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, disk-partitioning

I am trying to automate fdisk utility on Linux in order to delete partitions on the attached disk device (USB /dev/sdb in this case) by using Python 3.

The script should execute the following commands:

1). sudo fdisk /dev/sdb                        // Executing fdisk on /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): 2). d /dev/sdb           // Trying to delete /dev/sdb partition.

Partition number (1-4, default 4): 3). 2       // Partition number 2

This is my Python code so far:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "fdisk", "/dev/sdb"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)    
proc.communicate(b'd /dev/sdb')    
proc.communicate(b'2')
```

Line1 and Line2 works perfectly fine, however Line3 gives me the following error:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): Partition number (1-4, default 4): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./testing.py", line 83, in <module>    
proc.communicate(b'2')    
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 786, in communicate    
self._stdin_write(input)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 741, in _stdin_write    
self.stdin.write(input)    
ValueError: write to closed file
```

Is it possible to use subprocesses to achieve this task without a user having to interact with the program?
Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Proc.communicate()` function will effectively end the bytes with an EOF signal. So what you can do is treat all your commands as being part of the same file. Try:

```
proc.communicate(b'd /dev/sdb\n2')
```

The `\n` is what you're sending to the program when you hit the enter key.